# Word request for the "weapon for which there is no defense"?

Tags: phrase-request

In Hindu mythology, there are several mentions of a weapon, for which there is no defense. When that weapon is aimed at the enemy, the end of enemy is certain. That weapon is referred to as [Bhahmastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmastra).

Can you suggest me a corresponding phrase that would mean the same thing, that native English speakers would use in everyday conversation?

Answer (score 1):

One might use "ace in a hole" but it is not used commonly in conversations. Some other phrases are

- card up one's sleeve
- ace up your sleeve
- key advantage
- trump

Answer (score 1):

Doomsday weapon or Doomsday device come to mind.

There are also "weapons of mass destruction", but that is mainly referring to contemporary weapons, such as nuclear bombs.

Apocalyptic can be used to describe something that can bring about "the apocalypse", where the world changes to an unrecognizable state - usually resulting in the death of most life. A weapon could be described as apocalyptic, but I think Doomsday weapon (or Doomsday device) would suit the phrase "weapon for which there is no defense" the most accurately.

A shorter phrase, and probably the most accurate would be: "weapon that can't be countered" or "weapon that can't be defended against" (which is basically the phrase you already have).

Answer (score 0):

You could describe it as an [Armageddon](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/armageddon) weapon. It is used in this way in a video called "[Putin's Armageddon weapon](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=508658340896192)".